# Copy into a struct the values of an array of char pointers

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

I'm currently developing a simple DMBS as university project. I'm having some issues at rebuilding a list after the qsort function takes place.

```
typedef struct S_Column{
    char field[32];
    struct S_Column *next;
} column;
```

```
void sort(column *head, int table_size){
    char *array[table_size];
    int array_counter=0;

    column *sort_cursor;
    sort_cursor=head;

    //build the array of pointers
    while(sort_cursor->next!=NULL){
        array[array_counter] = sort_cursor->field;
        sort_cursor=sort_cursor->next;
        array_counter++;
    }

    //sorting
    qsort(array, array_counter, sizeof(char*), stringCompare);
    sort_cursor=head;

    //rebuild the list
    for(int i = 0; i<array_counter; i++){
        printf("SORTED elem %d: %s\n", i, array[i]);
        strcpy(sort_cursor->field, array[i]);
        sort_cursor=sort_cursor->next;
    }


    free(sort_cursor);
}
```

```
static int stringCompare(const void* str1, const void* str2){
    return strcmp(*(const char**)str1, *(const char**)str2); 
}
```

In the sort function, I have issues at copying the value of `array[i]` into the structure field `sort_cursor->field`.

In particular, in the `//rebuild the list` section, when I print out values from `array[i]` variable or `sort_cursor->field` variable, the output contains replicated values.

I noticed that if I remove the `strcpy` function in that section, it prints out everything correctly.

My goal is to have a list of type `column` with correctly sorted values.

Comment: I'm missing something here: how is it that removing the `strcpy` call as you've already described is not the solution you're looking for?

Comment: I want to get the values from the array of pointers ```array``` and build the struct with those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use an array store the string vaule of `field`, instead of pointers.

Because when you do `strcpy(sort_cursor->field, array[i]);` in `rebuild the list` section, actually `sort_cursor->field` must equal to one pointer of `array[x]` , which you do assignment `array[array_counter] = sort_cursor->field;` in the `build the array of pointers` section.

Assume the `head`->field is equal to array[5], so when you do `strcpy`, you actually put array[0] to array[5], then i++, array[1] to array[2], etc.

That's the reason of duplicated values.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!.
I've changed the ```//build the array of pointers``` with:
```array[array_counter] = strdup(sort_cursor->field);```
Now it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

The overall problem seems to be to sort a linked list with character array values, which seem to be assumed to contain strings.  The code presented attempts to accomplish this by forming an array of pointers to the strings, sorting that array with `qsort()`, and then copying the values into their sorted places with `strcpy`.

In thinking about why that won't work, the asymmetry between loading the array and unloading it should be considered.  You are loading the array by copying in *pointers*, and reading out the result by copying out *the data to which they point*.  That's not inherently problem, but in your particular case, you are storing the copied-out results where others of the pointers point.  That's analogous to attempting to perform a swap without a temporary:

```
// not a viable swap implementation:
int a = 1, b = 2;
a = b;  // The original value of a is lost here, so
b = a;  // this does not have the effect that was naively intended
```

---

**If your linked list elements contained pointers instead of the arrays themselves**, then the `array` array in your sort function and storage managed by `qsort` would adequately fill the role of temporaries.  You could then copy the pointers back out by assignment, symmetrically to how you copy them in (without `strcpy`).

**If you cannot change the structure, but you can change the signature of the `sort()` function**, then you could consider sorting the linked list directly, by rewriting the links appropriately.  Because this would be likely to change which node is the list head, however you would need the function either to return the new head or to accept a double pointer, so that it can directly update the caller's list head pointer.  Merge sort is fast, scales well, and is easy to implement for linked lists.  You wouldn't need any copy in / copy out operations for that.

**If you must use `qsort()` and you cannot modify the function signature**, then your best bet is probably to sort the actual array values instead of pointers to them.  Something like this:

```
// Dynamic allocation is wisest if table_size is not sure to be small
char (*array)[32] = malloc(table_size * sizeof(*array));

int array_counter;
column *sort_cursor;

// populate the array of values
array_counter = 0;
for (sort_cursor = head; sort_cursor; xort_cursor = sort_cursor->next) {
    strcpy(array[array_counter++], sort_cursor->field);
}

// sort the array with qsort
qsort(array, array_counter, sizeof(*array), arrayCompare);

// copy the values back out
array_counter = 0;
for (sort_cursor = head; sort_cursor; xort_cursor = sort_cursor->next) {
    strcpy(sort_cursor->field, array[array_counter++]);
}

// Mustn't forget to free the array
free(array);
```

That relies on

```
static int arrayCompare(const void* str1, const void* str2) {
    return strcmp(*(const char (*)[32])str1, *(const char (*)[32])str2); 
}
```